# What is the co/end of a parametric adjunction, if not its co/unit?

Tags: ct.category-theory

A *parametric adjunction* is a pair of functors
$$
F : {\cal C}\times {\cal X} \to \cal D
$$
and
$$
G : {\cal D} \times {\cal X}^o \to \cal C
$$
such that there is an adjunction
$$
\hom(F(C,X),D) \cong \hom(C,G(D,X))
$$
natural in all arguments. Now, I've always been convinced that when $F,G$ is a parametric adjunction, the counit and unit 
$$
\epsilon : F(X,G(X,D)) \to D
$$
and
$$
\eta : C \to G(F(C,X),X)
$$
are respectively the initial cowedge and the terminal wedge of the functors ${\cal X}^o\times{\cal X}\to \cal D,C$ obtained from $F,G$. I can prove it in many cases, but not in the general one. Is it false in general? Am I using some additional property of $\cal C,D,X$ in the cases I have in mind (mainly all categories I can think of are cartesian, and in fact I use the universal property of the product at some point...)

Comment: I don't see how this works when everything is constant in $X$ ?

Comment: Uh, ok, so you need some assumptions on the functors and categories involved. Which ones?

Comment: I have no clues. When $\mathcal{X} = \{*\}$, or more generally when $F$ and $G$ are constant in $\mathcal{X}$ then it works if and only if $F$ and $G$ are (level wise) equivalences.